# NFCTagReaderSession not call didDetect with Mifare tag

Tags: ios, swift, core-nfc

I'm trying to read the Mifare tag. The code is

```
var tagSession: NFCTagReaderSession?

guard NFCTagReaderSession.readingAvailable else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Scanning Not Supported",
                message: "This device doesn't support tag scanning.",
                preferredStyle: .alert
            )
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        tagSession = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: [.iso14443, .iso15693], delegate: self, queue: nil)
        tagSession?.alertMessage = "Hold your iPhone near the item to learn more about it."
        tagSession?.begin()
```

```
func tagReaderSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession) {
        print("tagReaderSessionDidBecomeActive")
    }
    
    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        print("didInvalidateWithError")
    }
    
    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        print("didDetect")
    }
```

The didDetect is not called. I've already to configure the App to Detect NFC Tags https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app

Please help.

Comment: Is `tagSession` an object of your ViewController? Is your ViewController always present? Do you have a warning on the line `NFCTagReaderSession`? ie, is your VC correctly conforming to the delegate protocol: `NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate`?